# what is the best way to merge pdfs in java

Tags: java, pdf, merge

i need to  merge many (1000-5000 a4 ) pdfs in java what is the best way to do it in java ?

Comment: Are you using any specific Java PDF library?

Comment: See also [How to merge two PDF files into one in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).

> iText PDF: your Java-PDF library
>
> You can use iText to :
>
> - Serve PDF to a browser
> - Generate dynamic documents from XML files or databases
> - Use PDF's many interactive features
> - Add bookmarks, page numbers, watermarks, etc.
> - **Split, concatenate, and manipulate PDF pages**
> - Automate filling out of PDF forms
> - Add digital signatures to a PDF file
> - And much more...

Comment: I use the .net wrapper version of iText (iTextSharp) and can only recommend this library. It is very fast and easy to get to grips with. Plenty of examples on the interweb too on how to do what you're after with it.

Comment: +1, iText is the most powerful i guess, its the preferred PDF engine for most reporting tools

Answer (score 2):

Apache has a good library called [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)
Check out the documentation for the [PDFMergeUtility](http://www.pdfbox.org/javadoc/org/pdfbox/util/PDFMergerUtility.html)