# How to append a pdf to the jasper genererated pdf report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am generating a pdf file in Jasper. I need to merge this jasper generated pdf file with the uploaded pdf file.
How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `PDFMergeUtility` to merge the output of the report with the existing pdf. Take a look at this thread: [Merge two pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java). The only difference is that you should call this after the report generation, and take it from its reside location, but the process is the same. Hope it helps.