# How to merge List<PdfDocument> into a single PdfDocument

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I have a List with multiple PDFs , and I want to merge all of them into a single PdfDocument (im using iText) , and then transform this PdfDocument into a ByteArrayOutputStream (OR a byte[]).

```
public byte[] mergePdfDocumentsIntoAPdfDocument (List<PdfDocument> pdfDocuments){

 final ByteArrayOutputStream mergedPdfStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final PdfDocument mergedPdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(mergedPdfStream));


//I dont know how can I continue this
```

What should I do in order to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java

Comment: Im not using PDF Box

Comment: What library are you using? Please update your question.

Comment: Updated , im using iText

Comment: https://github.com/itext/i7js-samples/blob/develop/publications/book/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part2/chapter06/Listing_06_21_Concatenate.java

Comment: This will probably work but how can I transform the PdfDocument into a byte [] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public byte[] mergePdfDocumentsIntoAPdfDocument(List<PdfDocument> pdfDocuments){
    ByteArrayOutputStream mergedPdfStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfDocument resultDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(mergedPdfStream));

    for (PdfDocument doc : pdfDocuments) {
        int n = doc.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            PdfPage page = doc.getPage(i).copyTo(resultDoc);
            resultDoc.addPage(page);
        }
    }

    resultDoc.close();
    return mergedPdfStream.toByteArray();
}
```