# Is it possible to merge multiple pdf pages to one sheet of pdf and print in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, printing, pdf-generation

I am trying to create Java program, which can read multiple pdf files and merge them into a single pdf file.
Then print the PDF but while printing i need to merge multiple pdf pages in a single page and print.
Even if it is a new pdf created, that is fine for me.
I need some open source java pdf manipulation library to handle this.
I know one solution is while printing, select multiple printing option for muliple pages to one sheet. But the printer i can access doesn't have such capabilities.
Can anybody suggest some solution for this or is it possible in any other programming language?

Comment: Try reviewing this article [How to merge two PDF files into one in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java#answer-4874334)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am able to merge files easily. But bigger issue is making multiple pages into a single page.