# How to remove margin of a new pdf created using PdfDocument object in iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7, pdf-manipulation

As per my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422720/), I am trying to merge multiple pdf pages into a single page. I am able to convert multiple pages pdf file to a merged pdf file. But default margin is cutting my document after merging.

I tried adding Document object also. But somehow I am unable to remove margin.

```java
Document tempDoc = new Document(pdfDoc, pageSize);
tempDoc.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Sample code

```java
PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());

//logic of pdf manipulation
PdfFormXObject page = srcDoc.getPage(pageCount).copyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
canvas.addXObject(page, xPos, yPos);

canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());
```

Please suggest if I am  doing something wrong or is there any other way to remove margin using PdfDocument object.

Comment: You might be interested in the [PdfDenseMerger](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/AR/repos/i7js-samples/browse/samples/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/merge/PdfDenseMerger.java) and its helper class [PageVerticalAnalyzer](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/AR/repos/i7js-samples/browse/samples/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/merge/PageVerticalAnalyzer.java) in the [old iText 7 samples](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/AR/repos/i7js-samples/browse/samples/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/merge)

Comment: Other than that I'd need something more to analyze here, in particular self contained code and sample data to reproduce the issue.