# Merged 2 PDF files to a new file

Tags: java, arrays, file, pdf

I have 2 PDF files.

I read both files as byte arrays, `file1` and `file2`, and concatenate then to a third array `file3`.

When I write this third array to the file system, the created file size is the sum of `file1` and `file2`, but it shows only the content of `file1`.

Here is how I write the array to the file system:

```
try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
    stream.write(file3);
}
```

How can i see all pages of merged file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two PDF files into one in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java)

Comment: Like many file format, pdf is not just a text content, it has a defined structured with headers and footers. Simply concatenating both binary doesn't modify this structure. So the reader app doesn't know it should keep reading the file after it reaches the first footer. There are dedicated libraries to merge PDF, check the linked question.

Comment: It's actually even worse than described by @jhamon. Pdfs have to be read from the end where there is an offset from the start of file to certain core structures. As the value of the second file is now applied to the concatenation of both files, it points to some arbitrary position. You are lucky that something sensible is displayed at all.

Comment: [How to merge two PDF files into one in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java) is not an exact duplicate: It is more specialized as it focuses on merging using a specific PDF library, PDFBox. Nonetheless it's a good pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your input . @mkl Is there anyway to merge two PDF byte Array into one PDF without using any third party library?

Comment: *"Is there anyway to merge two PDF byte Array into one PDF without using any third party library?"* - As there is no explicit PDF support in the JRE: Only by effectively implementing a (specialized) PDF library yourself. Not an easy task. Plan for some months of programming... (I assume "calling external third party programs or web services" would for you be equivalent to "using third party libraries".)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions