# How to merge all the pdf files into one using java?

Tags: java, file, pdf, utility, pdfmerger

In a folder I have few pdf files, I want to merge all the files into one.using java how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two PDF files into one in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java)

Comment: Unfortunately you don't tell us which PDF library you use. The question @sukalogika refers to focuses on PDFBox, but there are a number of other libraries you can alternatively use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PDFMergerUtility` (https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/PDFMergerUtility.html) for this:

```
PDFMergerUtility pdfMerge = new PDFMergerUtility();
pdfMerge.addSource("/pdf1.pdf");
pdfMerge.addSource("/pdf2.pdf");
// Add as many pdfMerge.addSource("/pdfx.pdf"); as you want
pdfMerge.setDestinationFileName("/pdf-final.pdf");
pdfMerge.mergeDocuments();
```

This has also been extensively discussed and answered here: [How to merge two PDF files into one in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java)