# How to merge two or more base64 encoded PDF files into a single base 64 encoded PDF file in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, merge, base64

I am facing a situation where the system will receive multiple base64 encoded PDF files from a third party system.

I need to merge those base64 encoded strings into one PDF, by appending the PDF in order and generate a new base64 encoded PDF file in Java.

I found out that I could not just concat multiple base 64 encoded PDF files together to form a new single base 64 encoded PDF.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

[How to merge two PDF files into one in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585329/how-to-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-in-java) does not answer the question because it is not merging multiple base64 encoded PDF files, thank you.

Comment: There's two layers: 1. decode your input PDFs to `byte[]` (or temporary files, if they are big). 2. merge the two PDFs. 3. re-encode the result to Base64.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thank you for providing the general direction on how to handle it.