How to merge PDF chunks into one page with PDFBox
Let's say I have a general template template.pdf file. I can use use PDFBox and AcroForm to change field values.
Now, I want to add another template (line_template.pdf) to the same page (document) and repeat it a few times.
Conceptually this should work like like this (gray box is basically single page):

When I load the documents and use PDFMergerUtility - documents are added as new pages. However, I'd like to combine them into single page (overlay it as shown on the picture).
Is it possible with PDF Box to overlay documents (or forms to be precise) on each other like in the picture?
Code below merges two PDFs into two pages, which I don't want.
val document = PDDocument()

val template = PDDocument.load(File("template.pdf"))
// Update template fields

val line = PDDocument.load(File("line_template.pdf"))
// Update line fields

val merger = PDFMergerUtility()
merger.appendDocument(document, template)
merger.appendDocument(document, line)

document.save("invoice.pdf")
document.close();



This question is similar to: How to merge two PDF files into one in Java?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Luuk There is a very clear distinction - I don't want one file with multiple pages, i.e. two PDFs merged into one file with multiple pages but I want to merge two PDFs into single page file.

Despite not being marked as answer, it might contain valuable info, but I think this answer is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21894264/724039.

I've seen that answer already. It looked promising but I doubt it's going to work the way I need it. I keep checking PDFBox documentation and I may found some solution. First I need to try it out and see if it works as expected.

You can use LayerUtility like so:
// Load the two PDF documents
        val template = PDDocument.load(File("template.pdf"))
        val line = PDDocument.load(File("line_template.pdf"))

        // Create a new document where the combined page will be added
        val combinedDoc = PDDocument()

        try {
            // Create a new page in the combined document with the size of the first document's first page
            val page1 = template.getPage(0)
            val mediaBox = page1.mediaBox
            val combinedPage = PDPage(mediaBox)
            combinedDoc.addPage(combinedPage)

            // Use LayerUtility to combine pages
            val layerUtility = LayerUtility(combinedDoc)

            // Import the first pages from both documents as form XObjects
            val form1 = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(template, 0)
            val form2 = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(line, 0)
            val form3 = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(line, 0)

            // Start a content stream to add the form XObjects
            val contentStream = PDPageContentStream(combinedDoc, combinedPage)

            // Draw the content of the template document's page at the original position
            contentStream.saveGraphicsState()
            contentStream.drawForm(form1)
            contentStream.restoreGraphicsState()

            // Draw the content of the line document's page at the middle of the page
            contentStream.saveGraphicsState()
            // Transform to place the second form at the middle
            val translateYMiddle = - mediaBox.height * 0.5F

            contentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(0f, translateYMiddle))
            contentStream.drawForm(form2)
            contentStream.restoreGraphicsState()

            // Draw the content of the line document's page at the quarter of page height
            contentStream.saveGraphicsState()
            // Transform to place the second form at the quarter of page height
            val translateYQuarter = - mediaBox.height * 0.75F

            contentStream.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(0f, translateYQuarter))
            contentStream.drawForm(form3)
            contentStream.restoreGraphicsState()

            // Close the content stream
            contentStream.close()

            // Save the combined document
            combinedDoc.save("combined.pdf")
        } finally {
            // Close all documents
            template.close()
            line.close()
            combinedDoc.close()
        }

